# How do I call the core content component in my custom component in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

My custom component has to call the core content component and create an entry in the #__content table with proper values. When I add a new article in the article manger I have to give only a title as mandatory field value and other values will be created automatically. I want to pretend this in my custom component.

Comment: Sorry but I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve here. Can you please explain in more detail along with your code?

Comment: I want to create a dummy valid article (content table entry) through my custom component. I inserted into table #__content values title, alias, state, introtext, catid and so on but don't know the way to add other dependencies like asset_id. So I want to add an article through my custom componet with only giving the value 'title'. (I am sorry i couldn't add the coding right now)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the database table directly load the `ContentModelArticle` from `com_content` and use the model to create new articles. This will generate the `alias` for you, do all of ACL etc based on the View Access and let any system or content plugins have a look at the article and do whatever they do.

`ContentModelArticle` extends from `JModelAdmin` so you can use it's `->save($data)` method. Where `$data` is the `array` of content to bind to the new `ContentModelArticle` in the `save()` method.

So, a basic example would be :

```
// Create our data with some sample code
$data['title'] = 'My Title';
$data['catid'] = 10;          /* NB. this is just an example category Id obviously you'll need to provide a suitable catid for your site */
$data['articletext'] = 'Starting text...'; /* From memory you can't have an empty article.*/

// Get the Article model
$articleModel = $this->getModel('Article', 'ContentModel', array());

// Then save it:
$articleModel->save($data);
```

Obviously you can populate as many fields as you want, including `state`, `publish_up`, `publish_down`, `create_by` and lots of others — just look at the structure of the content table in the database `#__content` to see the various columns and their type.

*NB: This is untested code just typed into the browser. It's also been a while since I did any 2.x stuff.*

Finally, as this question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I got the idea but
I am loading the model
`JLoader::import(‘article’, JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . ‘components’ . DS . ‘com_content’ . DS . ‘models’ );`
to ceate a new article in my componet.
However, the article.php model calls
`require_once JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.’/helpers/content.php’;`
and JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR points to my own component
How to resolve this?